# Pandas: How to associate timestamps to crosstab data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly

I have a huge dataframe with hundrends of columns and hundreds of thousands of rows. I process a few of the columns by using `pd.crosstab` and `melt` to get the data into a format that can be plotted easily. The dataframe `df` looks like this;

```
Time    Speed    Height
1       100      200
2       150      220
3       500      270
4       500      270
5       900      245
6       150      269
7       100      220
```

I'm basically just counting the number of instances at each point of Speed and Height and plotting it on a Scatter graph. ;

```
new_df = pd.crosstab(df['Speed'], df['Height'].fillna('n/a'))

plot_df = new_df.reset_index() 
plot_df = plot_df.melt(id_vars="Speed")
plot_df = plot_df.rename(columns={"index": "Speed",
                                "variable": "Height",
                                "value": "Count"})
```

I'm using plotly, so I can use the new `Count` column as the marker size on the graph, but I also use it in hovertext to display the count value along with the X & Y values for that point. `plot_df` ends up looking like;

```
Speed    Height   Count
100        200        1
150        200        0
500        200        0
900        200        0
500        200        0
100        220        1
150        220        1
500        220        0
900        220        0
500        220        0
100        245        0
150        245        0
500        245        0
900        245        1
500        245        0
100        269        0
150        269        1
500        269        0
900        269        0
500        269        0
100        270        0
150        270        0
500        270        2
900        270        0
500        270        0
```

This gave me the idea of somehow relating the Time data to the crosstab data and further into `plot_df` so that I can use it as hover data and I can't find any useful information on how to do this.

How can I do this? The output would look something like;

```
Speed    Height   Count    Time/Index
100        200        1        1
150        200        0        0
500        200        0        0
900        200        0        0
500        200        0        0
100        220        1        7
150        220        1        2
500        220        0        0
900        220        0        0
500        220        0        0
100        245        0        0
150        245        0        0
500        245        0        0
900        245        1        5
500        245        0        0
100        269        0        0
150        269        1        6
500        269        0        0
900        269        0        0
500        269        0        0
100        270        0        0
150        270        0        0
500        270        2        3, 4
900        270        0        0
500        270        0        0
```

Answer (score 1):

Idea is first aggregate by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and `join` and then add `0` with `melt` alternative - [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
new_df = (df.assign(Time = df['Time'].astype(str))
            .groupby(['Speed','Height'])['Time']
            .agg([('Count','size'),('Time', ', '.join)])
            .unstack(fill_value=0)
            .stack()
            .sort_index(level=[1,0])
            .reset_index())

print (new_df)
    Speed  Height  Count  Time
0     100     200      1     1
1     150     200      0     0
2     500     200      0     0
3     900     200      0     0
4     100     220      1     7
5     150     220      1     2
6     500     220      0     0
7     900     220      0     0
8     100     245      0     0
9     150     245      0     0
10    500     245      0     0
11    900     245      1     5
12    100     269      0     0
13    150     269      1     6
14    500     269      0     0
15    900     269      0     0
16    100     270      0     0
17    150     270      0     0
18    500     270      2  3, 4
19    900     270      0     0
```

Comment: This looks like it would work perfectly. I am getting a TypeError on the .agg line though; TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found

Comment: It seems that .astype(str) isn't converting everything in 'Time' to string.. for some reason the error throws on the 148874th element. In that row, the value for 'Speed' is 500 and the 'Height value is negative at -200. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: @Iceberg_Slim - Intersting, how working if change `.astype(str)` to `.apply(str)` ?

Comment: @Iceberg_Slim - Is possible see only problematic rows? What kind of data are there?

Comment: @Iceberg_Slim - Are data confidental? Because it seems same data related problem.

Comment: @jezreal - I am very sorry but it turns out that this does not work. If I remove the string conversion in the .agg line and convert to string in 'df' in an earlier line then we get the code to complete. However 'Count' is always 1 with this solution, where it should increase with number of instances.

Comment: @Iceberg_Slim - I ask if not is possible create pickle and share real data?

Comment: [`DataFrame.to_pickle`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html)

Comment: The data is confidential, Sorry!

Comment: @Iceberg_Slim - Then really hard find problem :(

Comment: @jezreal I have a pickle file where the data is randomised and cannot be identified. Where can I put this for you?

Comment: @Iceberg_Slim - Is possible sent it to my email from my profile?

Comment: @Iceberg_Slim - Run pandas code from my profile for my email

Comment: @Iceberg_Slim - Email was sent.